# Does the group $\mathbb{R}^{\times} / \mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ have a subgroup of order 5?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Does the group $\mathbb{R}^{\times} / \mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ have a subgroup of order 5?

I don't know how I should approach this problem. Could you give me some hints on how to solve this? A more general explanation on how to check if a group $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $n$ would be more appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since subgroups of prime order are cyclic, the question is equivalent to: Is there an element of $\mathbb{R}^{\times}/\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ of order $5$? Equivalently, is there a non-zero real number $r$ with $r^5 \in \mathbb{Q}$, but $r \notin \mathbb{Q}$? Well, of course, for example $r=\sqrt[5]{2}$.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure I understood it correctly...if we alter the problem a little bit and let $G = (\mathbb{R},+)/(\mathbb{Q},+)$, then we can say that there is no such non-zero real number $r$ with $5r \in \mathbb{Q}$, but $r \not\in \mathbb{Q}$. Is that right?

Comment: You mean $(\mathbb{R},+)/(\mathbb{Q},+)$? Yes, this has no torsion.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Is there a non-zero real number $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ that is irrational, but whose 5th power is rational?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your general question, if $G$ is finite, then Lagrange's theorem gives a necessary condition for the existence of a subgroup $H$ of order $n$, namely that $n$ divides the order of $G$. However, this is not sufficient in general. For supersolvable groups it is sufficient. 
If $G$ is an infinite group, then the existence of a subgroup $H$ of order $n$ means that there exists an element $g\in G$ of finite order $n$. Here there are many possibilities. The group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ has no subgroup $H$ of oder $n>1$. On the other hand there are infinite groups, even finitely-generated ones, where *every* non-trivial subgroup is finite, e.g., the [Tarski-monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group), or [Grigorchuk group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group).